# Is it possible to change VS Code settings with code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to manipulate settings in VS Code by writing code against them?

| **Example:** |  |
| --- | --- |
| Filename: | `assets.test.md` |
| Extension: | [`Paste Image`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mushan.vscode-paste-image) |
| Extension setting: | `pasteImage.defaultName` |
| Build-in variable to manipulate: | `${currentFileNameWithoutExt}` |
| **Desired code** (crux of the question) | `replace(${currentFileNameWithoutExt}, '.', '-')` |
| Goal: | Replace all '.' from filename with '-' for asset name |

Comment: Have you thought about modifying the extension code to add another built-in variable, e.g. `$(currentFileNameAsAsset)` to the substitution table in `paster.ts`?

Comment: Good idea, but I don't know TypeScript/JavaScript to be able to do such a thing.

Comment: It looks like the code is simple enough, if you look at the repository, but I wouldn't know how to rebuild it.  I hope someone else here can help on this.